# Can we use OpenShift instead of OpenStack?

Tags: openshift, openstack, fiware

We found out that Openshift is more suitable for our solution:

Could Openshift Origin be used to replace OpenStack for FIWARE Lab?

Comment: You haven't provided anything close to enough information to answer this question.  OpenShift and OpenStack provide very different models; which one is best suited for your needs depends entirely on your own requirements.  Even with more information in the question this would really be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we would like to install an official Fiware Lab it's mandatory to use OpenStack or we could use OpenShift?

Comment: Upvoting the helpful answers will be an encouragement..

Answer (score 3):

OpenStack and OpenShift are not interchangeable technologies, they do very different things. So, if OpenStack is required, then OpenShift Origin would not be able to replace it.

[OpenStack](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/openstack) is a virtualization platform for managing virtual machines in both public and private cloud environments.

[OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) is built around Kubernetes and Docker made enterprise ready. It's used for scheduling and managing docker containers, or can operate directly on your source code, and the docker containers can be transparent to developers.